# Why consider $P_n(\mathbb{R})$ a subspace of $C(\mathbb{R})$, rather than $P_{n}(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: polynomials

A space of polynomials $P_n(\mathbb{R})$ can be regarded to be a subspace of $C(\mathbb{R})$ (continuous functions).

However, to me this seems like a *stretch.*

Sure polynomials are continuous functions, but wouldn't a "stricter" subspace criterion mean that $P_n(\mathbb{R})$ would be a subset of "mainly" $P_{n}(\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: Do you mean to use the same subscript, $n$, for both $P_n(\Bbb R)$'s?

Comment: That it is a subspace of itself is not really an interesting information

Comment: But is it not a stretch of say it's a subset of continuous functions? I think $C(\mathbb{R})$ might be a lot larger set than $P_n(\mathbb{R})$. Thus, they aren't that "similar" even.

Comment: The assertion that $V$ is a subspace of $W$ says nothing about the relative sizes or the "similarity" of $V$ and $W$. $P_n(\mathbb{R})$ is a subset of $C(\mathbb{R})$ which is closed under the vector space operations and contains $0$. So it satisfies the definition, and it's a subspace. There's nothing more to it!

Comment: What do you mean by 'a stretch'? It's just a fact.